# My django app is not activating after restarting my PC

Tags: python, django

When I start a new Django Project it works perfectly but after I shutdown or restart my PC it does not work. Even though I have activated my virtual environment it keeps giving me errors.

This what the error says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\SUCCESS-AKINYEMI\Desktop\studybud\manage.py", line 11, in main
 from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\SUCCESS-AKINYEMI\Desktop\studybud\manage.py", line 22, in main()
 File "C:\Users\SUCCESS-AKINYEMI\Desktop\studybud\manage.py", line 13, in main
 raise ImportError( ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

I tried it on another laptop and it worked, but it is not working on my own laptop.

Comment: Do you have multiple python versions installed? Are you sure you're in the right virtualenv? If you run `pip freeze` do you actually have django installed?

Comment: "Even though I have activated my virtual environment"—are you sure you activated the right one?

Comment: How do you run your django app? Are you using CMD or PowerShell? Or some other way? If you are running `manage.py runserver` in CMD or PowerShell, do you get the same error when you close the shell window and open a new one?

Answer (score 0):

make sure that python is added to the path
in windows try
windows logo + pause -> Advanced system settings -> Environment variables
if python it's not on the list add it.
for Value insert something like this

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\
```

also make sure that you use the keyword `py` in your commands
for example :

```
py manage.py runserver
```